# Why do some letters in my rigid body text simulation jump around like crazy?

Tags: rigid-body-simulation

I have this very simple text rigid body simulation, but it acts weird (it jumps around). Why does this happen and how can I stop this?

[image: animation showing the lower case 't' flying off weirdly]

[image]

I tried changing substeps per frames and solver iterations, but didn't help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you separated the text into separate objects you should have set the origin of each new object to the that object's geometry.

Also you would have benefitted from applying the rotation of the text.

You may want to adjust the mass settings of each letter for more realistic behavior.

Answer (score 6):

To answer why this happens:

Any rotation to that 't' happens around its origin.  Since it is offcenter, the rotation looks like this:

[image]

When the 't' collides with something, and the physics system tells it to have a rotation, this will cause an **undue** velocity to be given to the mesh in the rigid body sim.  It will likely end up clipping into an object and ejecting itself, or falling over and never properly coming to rest.